# How do you get the name of a generic class using reflection?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, class

How do you get the name of a generic class using reflection

eg

```
public class SomeGenericClass<T>
{
}

SomeGenericClass<int> test = new SomeGenericClass<int>();
```

`test.GetType().Name` returns "SomeGenericClass'1"

How do I get it to return "SomeGenericClass" without the '1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just the following?

```
test.GetType().Name.Split('\'')[0]
```

It works on non-generic classes too.

Comment: This would work but I was wondering if I could access the property directly?

Comment: Why doesn't it get the actual type of `SomeGenericClass<int>`?

Comment: @Petras: As neilwhitaker1 points out, the `'1` is actually part of the name (and refers to one generic type parameter). As far as the CLR is concerned, there is no typ called `SomeGenericClass`, but only one called `SomeGenericClass'1` - someone correct me if I'm wrong here.

Answer (score 4):

The '1 is part of the name, because, for example, `List<T>` and `List` (if I created such a class) are different classes.

'1 means that it has one type parameter. If you want to know the type of that parameter, use test.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

Answer (score 1):

```
enum.GetName(test.GetType(), test).ToString()
```